# Button not responding with ActionListener

Tags: jbutton, actionlistener

I added my buttons to the ActionListener, and the buttons seem to not do anything, as i assingned a task when the button is pressed, i even asked it to print somthing. I am trying to make a stock game in a gui. I have a book that teaches me how to do this, i dont know why it is not working.

```
package stock.gui.game;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.Random;
import java.lang.Thread;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.math.*;



public class StockGUIGame extends JFrame implements ActionListener{

    int linecount = 0;
    float[] stockpricebefore = {20.00f , 1090.00f , 60.00f , 35.00f , 160.00f, 70.00f, 95.00f, 15.00f };
    int[] downupdecider2 = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
    float[] downup2 = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
    //int linecount = 0;
    float netwoth = 0;
    String[] names  = {"Universe Express", "Digital Internet", "Garstump Motors", "Freedom Frinature", "Walter's Waters", "Tiger Toys", "Healthy Tastes", "Niagra Drinks"};
    float[] stockpricestart = {20.00f , 1090.00f , 60.00f , 35.00f , 160.00f, 70.00f, 95.00f, 15.00f };
    float[] stockprice = {20.00f , 1090.00f , 60.00f , 35.00f , 160.00f, 70.00f, 95.00f, 15.00f };
    int stockbuytrack = 0;
    int[] stocktobuy = {100, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
    int[] stockbuy = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
    int stocknow = 0;
    int days = 0;
    byte downupcounter[] = {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1};
    Random ran = new Random();
    float[] downup = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
    float finalstockprice = 0.00f;
    int[] downupdecider = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
    float[] downupmax = {6.00f, 4.00f, 4.00f, 4.00f, 0.1f, 8.00f, 10.00f, 4.00f};
    float[] downuptwomax = {3.00f, 2.00f, 2.00f, 2.00f, 0f, 4.00f, 5.00f, 2.00f};
    float[] downupsmall = {1.50f, 0.5f, 1.50f, 3.5f, 0.20f, 2.50f, 1.50f, 1.50f};
    float[] downuptwosmall = {0.75f, 0.25f, 0.50f, 1.50f, 0.10f, 1.00f, 0.50f, 0.50f};
    int[] stocknumber;
    int sharesbuy[] = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
    static float money = 1000.00f;
    String[] multiplier = {"1", "10", "100", "1,000", "10,000", "100,000", "1,000,000"};
    float assets = 0.00f;

    //JLabel lab = new JLabel("Universe Express | Digital Internet | Garstump Motors | Freedom Frinature | Walter's Waters | Tiger Toys | Healthy Tastes | Niagra Drinks | Net Worth             | Cash                |");
    JSlider stockslider = new JSlider(0, 10);
    JTextArea ss1 = new JTextArea(30, 216);
    JScrollPane s1 = new JScrollPane(ss1, ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS, ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
    JComboBox multi = new JComboBox(names);
    JComboBox mul = new JComboBox(multiplier);
    JButton buy = new JButton("Buy");
    JButton sell = new JButton("Sell");
    JCheckBox all = new JCheckBox("All");

    public StockGUIGame() throws InterruptedException{
        super("Stock Game");
        setSize(1550, 650);
        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JPanel pane = new JPanel();
        stockslider.setMajorTickSpacing(10);
        stockslider.setMajorTickSpacing(1);
        stockslider.setPaintTicks(true);
        stockslider.setPaintLabels(true);
        Font font = new Font("Courier New", Font.PLAIN, 12);
        ss1.setFont(font);
        //pane.add(lab);
        pane.add(s1);
        pane.add(buy);
        pane.add(sell);           
        pane.add(multi);
        pane.add(mul);
        pane.add(stockslider);
        pane.add(all);
        add(pane);
        all.addActionListener(this);
        ss1.append("Universe Express | Digital Internet | Garstump Motors | Freedom Frinature | Walter's Waters | Tiger Toys | Healthy Tastes | Niagra Drinks | Days                         | Net Worth             | Cash                |\n" );

        for (int l = 1; l == 1; ){

            Thread.sleep(900);
            days = days + 1;
            int tu = stockslider.getValue();
            String op = String.format("%d", tu);
            formula();
            print();
            ss1.setCaretPosition(ss1.getDocument().getLength());

        }

    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt){
        Object source = evt.getSource();
        if (source == buy){
            if ((stockprice[multi.getSelectedIndex()]) * (((int) Math.pow(10, (mul.getSelectedIndex()) / 10)) * stockslider.getValue()) < money){
                linecount = linecount - 1;
                ss1.append("Not enough money! Can buy" + Math.round((money - (money % stockprice[multi.getSelectedIndex()])) / stockprice[multi.getSelectedIndex()]));
            }  
            else if (all.isSelected() == true){
                stocktobuy[multi.getSelectedIndex()] = stocktobuy[multi.getSelectedIndex()] + Math.round((money - (money % stockprice[multi.getSelectedIndex()])) / stockprice[multi.getSelectedIndex()]);
                ss1.append("You bought " + Math.round((money - (money % stockprice[multi.getSelectedIndex()])) / stockprice[multi.getSelectedIndex()]) + " stocks of " + names[multi.getSelectedIndex()] + " at " + stockprice[multi.getSelectedIndex()] + " a share");
                linecount = linecount - 1;
                money = money - (stocktobuy[multi.getSelectedIndex()] * stockprice[multi.getSelectedIndex()]);
            }
            else{
                ss1.append("You bought " + ((int) Math.pow(10, (mul.getSelectedIndex()) / 10)) * stockslider.getValue() + " stocks of " + names[multi.getSelectedIndex()] + " at " + stockprice[multi.getSelectedIndex()] + " a share");
                stocktobuy[multi.getSelectedIndex()] = ((int) Math.pow(10, (mul.getSelectedIndex()) / 10)) * stockslider.getValue();
                money = money - (stocktobuy[multi.getSelectedIndex()] * stockprice[multi.getSelectedIndex()]);
                linecount = linecount - 1;
            }

        }
        else if (source == sell){
            if (stocktobuy[multi.getSelectedIndex()] + 1 < ((((int) Math.pow(10, (mul.getSelectedIndex()) / 10)) * stockslider.getValue() * stockprice[multi.getSelectedIndex()]))){
                linecount = linecount - 1;
            }
            else if (all.isSelected() == true){
                ss1.append("You sold " + Math.round((money - (money % stockprice[multi.getSelectedIndex()])) / stockprice[multi.getSelectedIndex()]) + " stocks of " + names[multi.getSelectedIndex()] + " at " + stockprice[multi.getSelectedIndex()] + " a share");    
                money = money + (stocktobuy[multi.getSelectedIndex()] * stockprice[multi.getSelectedIndex()]);
                stocktobuy[multi.getSelectedIndex()] = 0;
                linecount = linecount - 1;
            }
            else{
                ss1.append("You sold " + ((int) Math.pow(10, (mul.getSelectedIndex()) / 10)) * stockslider.getValue() + " stocks of " + names[multi.getSelectedIndex()] + " at " + stockprice[multi.getSelectedIndex()] + " a share");
                money = money + ((((int) Math.pow(10, (mul.getSelectedIndex()) / 10)) * stockslider.getValue() * stockprice[multi.getSelectedIndex()]) );
                stocktobuy[multi.getSelectedIndex()] = 0;
                linecount = linecount - 1;
            }
        }
    }


    private static void setLookAndFeel(){
        try{
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.nimbus.NinbusLookAndFeel");
        }
        catch(Exception exc){
            //ignore error
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        setLookAndFeel();
        StockGUIGame sguig = new StockGUIGame();

    }

    public void formula(){

        for (int b = 0; b < 8; b++ ){
            if (downupcounter[b] <  1){
                stockpricebefore[b] = stockprice[b];
            }
            downupdecider[b] = ran.nextInt(20);
            if (stockprice[b] > stockpricestart[b] * (1 + (days / 400.00f)) * 1.75f){
                downupdecider[b] = 10;
            }
            if (downupdecider[b] == 10){
                downup[b] = ((ran.nextFloat() * downupmax[b])  * ((stockpricestart[b] * (1 + (days / 400.00f))) / stockprice[b])) - downuptwomax[b];
                if (downup[b] > 1.5f * downupmax[b]){
                    downup[b] = (float)downupmax[b];
                }
            }

            if (downupcounter[b] == 1){         
                downup[b] = (ran.nextFloat() * downupmax[b]) - downuptwomax[b] ;
                downupcounter[b] = 0;
            }

            downupdecider2[b] = ran.nextInt(4);

            if (downupdecider2[b] == 2){
                downup2[b] = (ran.nextFloat() * (downupmax[b] * 2.00f)) - (downuptwomax[b] * 2) ;
            }

            if (downupcounter[b] == 1){         
                downup2[b] = (ran.nextFloat() * (downupmax[b] * 2.00f)) - (downuptwomax[b] * 2);
                downupcounter[b] = 0;
            }




            finalstockprice = ((((downup[b] + downup2[b]) + (ran.nextFloat() * ( downupsmall[b]) - downuptwosmall[b])) * stockprice[b]) / 100.00f) + stockprice[b];
            stockprice[b] = Math.round(finalstockprice * 100) / 100.00f ;

            if (ran.nextInt(99) == 59){
                stockprice[b] = Math.round((stockprice[b] - ((ran.nextFloat() / 4.00f) * stockprice[b])) * 100) / 100.00f;
            }
            if (ran.nextInt(99) == 45){
                stockprice[b] = Math.round((stockprice[b] + ((ran.nextFloat() / 4.00f) * stockprice[b])) * 100) / 100.00f;
            }


        }



    }

    public void print(){


        ss1.append("$");
        if (stockprice[0] < stockpricebefore[0])
            ss1.append( stockprice[0] + "-");
        else if (stockprice[0] > stockpricebefore[0]){
            ss1.append( stockprice[0] + "+");
        }
        else{
            ss1.append( stockprice[0] + "=");
        }
        for (int c = 0; c < 16 - (Float.toString(stockprice[0]).length()) - 1; c++){
            ss1.append(" ");
        }
        ss1.append("|");
        ss1.append("$");
        if (stockprice[1] < stockpricebefore[1])
            ss1.append( stockprice[1] + "-");
        else if (stockprice[1] > stockpricebefore[1]){
            ss1.append( stockprice[1] + "+");
        }
        else{
            ss1.append( stockprice[1] + "=");
        }
        for (int c = 0; c < 17 - (Float.toString(stockprice[1]).length()) - 1; c++){
            ss1.append(" ");
        }
        ss1.append("|");
        ss1.append("$");
        if (stockprice[2] < stockpricebefore[2])
            ss1.append( stockprice[2] + "-");
        else if (stockprice[2] > stockpricebefore[2]){
            ss1.append( stockprice[2] + "+");
        }
        else{
            ss1.append( stockprice[2] + "=");
        }
        for (int c = 0; c < 16 - (Float.toString(stockprice[2]).length()) - 1; c++){
            ss1.append(" ");
        }
        ss1.append("|");
        ss1.append("$");
        if (stockprice[3] < stockpricebefore[3])
            ss1.append( stockprice[3] + "-");
        else if (stockprice[3] > stockpricebefore[3]){
            ss1.append( stockprice[3] + "+");
        }
        else{
            ss1.append( stockprice[3] + "=");
        }
        for (int c = 0; c < 18 - (Float.toString(stockprice[3]).length()) - 1; c++){
            ss1.append(" ");
        }
        ss1.append("|");
        ss1.append("$");
        if (stockprice[4] < stockpricebefore[4])
            ss1.append( stockprice[4] + "-");
        else if (stockprice[4] > stockpricebefore[4]){
            ss1.append( stockprice[4] + "+");
        }
        else{
            ss1.append( stockprice[4] + "=");
        }
        for (int c = 0; c < 16 - (Float.toString(stockprice[4]).length()) - 1; c++){
            ss1.append(" ");
        }
        ss1.append("|");
        ss1.append("$");
        if (stockprice[5] < stockpricebefore[5])
            ss1.append( stockprice[5] + "-");
        else if (stockprice[5] > stockpricebefore[5]){
            ss1.append( stockprice[5] + "+");
        }
        else{
            ss1.append( stockprice[5] + "=");
        }
        for (int c = 0; c < 11 - (Float.toString(stockprice[5]).length()) - 1; c++){
            ss1.append(" ");
        }
        ss1.append("|");
        ss1.append("$");
        if (stockprice[6] < stockpricebefore[6])
            ss1.append( stockprice[6] + "-");
        else if (stockprice[6] > stockpricebefore[6]){
            ss1.append( stockprice[6] + "+");
        }
        else{
            ss1.append( stockprice[6] + "=");
        }
        for (int c = 0; c < 15 - (Float.toString(stockprice[6]).length()) - 1; c++){
            ss1.append(" ");
        }
        ss1.append("|");
        ss1.append("$");
        if (stockprice[7] < stockpricebefore[7])
            ss1.append( stockprice[7] + "-");
        else if (stockprice[7] > stockpricebefore[7]){
            ss1.append( stockprice[7] + "+");
        }
        else{
            ss1.append( stockprice[7] + "=");
        }
        for (int c = 0; c < 14 - (Float.toString(stockprice[7]).length()) - 1; c++){
            ss1.append(" ");
        }
        ss1.append("|");
        ss1.append(" ");
        ss1.append("Day: " + days );
        for (int c = 0; c < 30 - (Float.toString(days).length()) - 4; c++){
            ss1.append(" ");
        }
        ss1.append("|");
        ss1.append(" ");
        ss1.append("$");
        assets = (money + (stocktobuy[0] * stockprice[0]) + (stocktobuy[1] * stockprice[1]) + (stocktobuy[2] * stockprice[2]) + (stocktobuy[3] * stockprice[3]) + (stocktobuy[4] * stockprice[4]) + (stocktobuy[5] * stockprice[5]) + (stocktobuy[6] * stockprice[6]) + (stocktobuy[7] * stockprice[7]));
        String str1 = Float.toString(money);
        String str2 = Float.toString(assets);
        ss1.append(str2);
        for (int c = 0; c < 22 - (Float.toString(assets).length()) - 1; c++){
            ss1.append(" ");
        }
        ss1.append("|");
        ss1.append(" ");
        ss1.append("$");
        ss1.append(str1);
        for (int c = 0; c < 20 - (Float.toString(assets).length()) - 1; c++){
            ss1.append(" ");
        }
        ss1.append("|");
        linecount = linecount + 1;
        ss1.append("\n");
        if (linecount == 28){
            linecount = 0;
            ss1.append("Universe Express | Digital Internet | Garstump Motors | Freedom Frinature | Walter's Waters | Tiger Toys | Healthy Tastes | Niagra Drinks | Days                         | Net Worth             | Cash                |\n" );
        }

    }



}
```

Comment: A book taught you the syntax `for (int l = 1; l == 1; )`? That is the same as saying `while (true)` since you don't update the variable in the loop.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the ActionListener to the buttons.

You do `all.addActionListener(this)` but that is a checkbox and you don't check for that source in the `actionPerformed`.

I think you need

```
buy.addActionListener(this);
sell.addActionListener(this);
```